# How to fix the space after two columns inside a row the third one starts at the end of the second creating a big space?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have 2 columns inside a row and a column outside of the first row.
row
 col-1
 col-2
col-3
The problem is that the col-3 starts at the end of col-1 so in desktop mode there is a gap between col-1 and col-3 and the gap keeps expanding as big as col-2 is.
How I make in a way that col-3 dont start after col-2 height and by consequence there is no big space between col-1 and col-3? I did tried putting all cols inside row and put order-first and order-last

This is how it looks:

```
|col-1  ||col-2|
|       ||     |
 ------- |     |
         |     |
---------
col-3
---------
```

This is how it should look:

```
|col-1  ||col-2|
|       ||     |
 ------- |     |
col-3    |     |
---------|     |
```

I did tried putting all cols inside row and put order-first and order-last

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
   col-1
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4"> 
     col-2
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8 pull-left">
       col-3
  </div>
</div>
```

Expected result should be that there is no space after col-1 with col-2. So col-3 should not start after col-2 height.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use the bootstrap flex css to achieve this since it is much easier. I have added a test code. Hope this helps your problem

HTML

```
<div class="flex-row">
  <div class="flex-column">
    <div class="col-md-8 red">
      Column 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 red">
      Column 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4 green">
  Column 3
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flex-row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.flex-column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 10px;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

JS Fiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/SJ_KIllshot/pqtxL9bs/

Comment: I tried them all and none worked. I am basically trying to achieve the YouTube layout when watching a video. Where you have col1 the video player, col2 the next videos and col3 right below col1. The problem is col3 is starting after col3 ends creating a gap between col1 and 3 in desktop mode.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

Here is a basic YouTube example using flexbox. You can clean up the CSS.

CodePen

https://codepen.io/matrixme/pen/wbqvZb

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col--one">
            <div class="row video">
                <h2>Video</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="row forum">
                <h2>Forum</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li class="thread"></li>
                    <li class="thread"></li>
                    <li class="thread"></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col--two">
            <h2>Related</h2>
            <ul>
                <li class="thumbnail">

                </li>
                <li class="thumbnail">

                </li>
                <li class="thumbnail">

                </li>
                <li class="thumbnail">

                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
  width: 100vw;
  margin: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #323232;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: flex-start;
}

h2 {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.col--one {
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
}

.col--two {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-left: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.video {
  position: relative;
  height: 350px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE;
}

.forum {
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: #dddddd;
  position: relative;
}

ul {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.thread {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 90%;
}


.thumbnail {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  width: 80%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I tried them all and none worked. I am basically trying to achieve the YouTube layout when watching a video. Where you have col1 the video player, col2 the next videos and col3 right below col1. The problem is col3 is starting after col3 ends creating a gap between col1 and 3 in desktop mode.

Comment: @dianesis I created a CodePen and included example

Answer (score 0):

```css
.content {
  background: #999;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.h50 {
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row eq-height">
    <div class="col-8">
      <div class="h-50 content">Atul</div>
      <div class="h-50 content">Rajput</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      <div class="content h-100">Kumar</div>
    </div>  
  </div>
</div>
```

There is no need to write so much css for this, just change the HTML structure and a little CSS will help you.

Comment: I tried them all and none worked. I am basically trying to achieve the YouTube layout when watching a video. Where you have col1 the video player, col2 the next videos and col3 right below col1. The problem is col3 is starting after col3 ends creating a gap between col1 and 3 in desktop mode.